# ASP delimiter unexpectedly renders verbatim

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working in a Web Forms application and I'm seeing some strange behaviour I don't understand. I'm just trying to output the value of a string to an html attribute in the `<head>`.

`<meta itemprop="name" content="<%= EventTitle %>">`

This does not do what I expect. Rather than rendering the value of `EventTitle`, it outputs verbatim

[image: ASP Delimiters not working]

If I concatenate the `EventTitle` string in the `<meta>` tag with an empty string, the contents of `EventTitle` are rendered as I expect.

`<meta itemprop="name" content="<%= "" + EventTitle %>">`

Produces

`<meta itemprop="name" content="SomeEventTitle">`

My question is, why *doesn't* `<%= EventTitle %>` work the way I expect it to? And what exactly is happening under the hood to force it to work properly when I concatenate it with an empty string?